# Clicking on notification from an app with no Icons does not invoke the app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am working on one of the embedded app that I need to sunset, if I hide the icon of the application through code, then the applicaton does not get invoked when I click on the system trey notification to laucn it.

I have tried to simulate this in a sample app and it does not even work there as well. Is there any limitation from Google for Apps without launcher icon for not being invoked from notifications?

My Applicaiton class code:

```
class MainApplication : Application() {


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    hideAppIcon()
    showNotification()

}

private fun hideAppIcon() {
    val p = packageManager
    val componentName = ComponentName(
        this,
        com.icon.notification.rel.MainActivity::class.java
    ) // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        componentName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    )
}

private fun showNotification(){

    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
        val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel("local_notification", name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)



        // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "local_notification")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)//@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)


        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notify(1000000001, builder.build())
        }
    }
}
```

}

My Activity Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        this.finish()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

}

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have updated my question details. Once the application launches it first hides the icon and then shows the notification. After that i kill the app but can still click the notification in system trey to open it. When I do so, I am not taken to the application main activity. And if i enable the user icon for the app then i am taken to Main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;
private void showNotification(Context context, String msg) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int notifyID = 1;
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
        CharSequence name = "Football90 Reminder";// The user-visible name of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Football90")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        // Issue the notification.
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);
    }else {
        alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //Create notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setContentTitle("Football90").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg).setAutoCancel(true);
        alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        //notiy notification manager about new notification
        alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Try this method to show notification.

Comment: Tried the answer but has no effect on the end result as it still does not launch the main Activity. This does not seem to be an issue with how we  set the intent in notification but something with intent filters being resolved.

Comment: just for information i am testing it on API 26 devices

Comment: Try to read this page https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: Have gone throug this before , but could not find some thing relavant to this issue. Is there anything specific in the documentation that I am missing ?

Comment: I think you should move snippets of code from Application class to your activity

Comment: since i can not post the production code here, the code that I have posted is a POC , in the actual production app I am doing the same. I will still try it but I do not thik that will make a difference as it is not working in my PROD app that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the reason and wanted to share with everyone.

In order to hide the applicaiton icon completly I was disabling the launcher activity, while doing so the intent filter for that also gets disabled since the entire component gets disabled. As the intent that was being launched while clicking on notification takes you to the launcher activity based on intent filter only, the intent is thrown but the launcher activity is disabled and so is its intent filter, causing the intent to do nothing.

Hope this helps for all who tend to hide the applicaiton icon completly.